# Regex Python findall. Making things nonredundant

Tags: python, regex, sequence, redundancy

So what I'm trying to do is have a function that finds a sequence 'ATG' in a string and then from there moves along the string in units of 3 until it finds either a 'TAA', 'TAG', or 'TGA' (ATG-xxx-xxx-TAA|TAG|TGA)

To do this, I wrote this line of code (where `fdna` is the input sequence)

```
ORF_sequences = re.findall(r'ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',fdna)
```

I then wanted to add 3 requirements:

1. Total length must be 30
2. Two places before the ATG there must be either an A or a G to be detected (A|G-x-x-A-T-G-x-x-x)
3. The next place after the ATG would have to be a G (A-T-G-G-x-x)

To execute this part, I changed my code to:

```
ORF_sequence_finder = re.findall(r'[AG]..ATGG..(?:...){7,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',fdna)
```

**What I want instead of having all of these limits would be to have requirement 1 (greater or equal to 30 characters) and then have EITHER requirement 2 (A|G-x-x-A-T-G-x-x-x) OR requirement 3 (A-T-G-G-x-x) OR both of those.**

*If I split the above line up into two and appended them to a list, they get out of order and have repeats.*

Here are a few examples of the different cases:

```
sequence1 = 'AGCCATGTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGTGAAAA'
sequence2 = 'ATCCATGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGTAG'
sequence3 = 'AGCCATGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGTAG'    
sequence4 = 'ATGGGGTGA'
```

---

```
sequence1 = 'A**G**CC*ATG*TGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG*TGA*AAA'
```

`sequence1` would be accepted by criteria because it follows requirement 2 (A|G-x-x-A-T-G-x-x-x) and its length is >= 30.

```
sequence2 = 'ATCC*ATG***G**GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG*TAG*
```

`sequence2` would be accepted because it follows requirement 3 (A-T-G-G-x-x) and its length is >=30

```
sequence3 = 'A**G**CC*ATG***G**GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG*TGA*AAA'
```

`sequence3` would be accepted because it fulfills both requirement 2 and 3 while also having >=30 character.

```
sequence4 = 'ATGGGGTGA'
```

`sequence4` would NOT be accepted because its not >= 30, does not follow requirement 2 or requirement 3.

**So basically, I want it to accept sequences that either follow requirement 2 AND/OR requirement 3 (or both) while satisfying requirement 1.**

*How can I split this up without then adding duplicates (in cases where both occur) and getting out of order?*

Comment: I think you're looking for perl. In any sane language you really wouldn't want to do this with regex.

Comment: Should the `[AG]..` be counted in the length or does only the string starting at `ATG` has to be `>= 30`?

Comment: only the ATG . . . TGA|TAA|TAG should be included in the 30 . what i was doing before was having the sequence include [AG..] and then using a for loop later to sequence[3:] to clip the first few ones off but i wouldn't be able to do that to ones that only included [A-T-G-G-xxx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the possible `[AG]..` should be included in the length requirement you can use:

```
r'(?x) (?: [AG].. ATG | ATG G.. )  (?:...){7,}? (?:TAA|TAG|TGA)'
```

Or if you don't want to include `[AG]..` in the match you could use lookarounds:

```
r'(?x) ATG (?: (?<=[AG].. ATG) | (?=G) ) (?:...){8,}? (?:TAA|TAG|TGA)'
```

Comment: thank you so much. do you know anywhere I can go to learn more about what exactly is happening in this line of code ? this works perfectly with everything i've tried but some of the syntax is foreign to me and i want to be able to understand it so i can troubleshoot things later

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: Scroll down here to see them explained: http://regex101.com/r/bR9sK1 and http://regex101.com/r/uC2lJ7 For more details on the constructs check your regex reference, for example [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: if you were to make a variable out of the length (i.e. the 7 position) . . . how would you do this? i showed my attempts here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673739/using-format-to-use-variable-in-regex-findall-object-python