# Using .format to use variable in regex findall object. Python

Tags: regex, string, variables, format, findall

I saw some examples of this here but it did not answer my question:
[Python Regular Expression findall with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059596/python-regular-expression-findall-with-variable)

i'm trying to use a variable instead of the 9 but i can't seem to figure it out

```
value = 9
ORF = re.findall(r'ATG(?:(?!TAA|TAG|TGA)…){  value  ,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',seq) 
#obviously doesn't work or i wouldn't have made this post
```

I tried:

```
value = 9
ORF = re.findall(r'ATG(?:(?!TAA|TAG|TGA)…){  {}  ,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)'.format(value),seq)
```

but got the error:

```
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
```

then I tried:

```
value = r'{}'.format(9)
ORF = re.findall(r'ATG(?:(?!TAA|TAG|TGA)...){value,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',seq)
```

and got no error but it didn't work when i looked downstream

**How can I get this variable to work in my regular expression?**

Comment: You didn't use .format in your second attempt.  In general though, you'll need to quote format specifier characters in the string.  It's usually easier to just use string concatenation (i.e. `+`).

Comment: @thebjorn i tried adding it in before like they did in the link i provided for a similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is complaining that there are other `{` and `}` in your string not used for format, and it doesn't know how to tell the difference.  In a format string, braces are escaped by doubling them.

You also need to escape any regex characters in your `value`.

So perhaps:

```
ORF = re.findall(
    r'ATG(?:(?!TAA|TAG|TGA)…){{{},}}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)'
        .format(re.escape(value)),
    seq)
```

In a case like this, though, I doubt anyone would fault you for using `%`-formatting or good old string concatenation instead  :)

Comment: i ended up using string concatenation but i want to practice the .format for later. nice profile pic btw  vaporeon was my fav